# Can you pre-load related data such that your relationships are cached in ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple hasMany/belongsTo relationship that looks like this

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  bar: belongsTo('bar', { async: true})
});
App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  foos: hasMany('foo', { async: true})
});
```

I have situations in my route code that fire off a request and when the response comes back I access the related "bar" model as I filter down / etc

```
this.store.all('foo').clear();
var fooz = self.store.all('foo'); //new code
return this.store.find('foo').then(function(response) {
  var filtered = response.filter(function(foo) {
    return foo.get('bar').get('name') === 'bazz';
  });
  //other code that would normally be executed top-down
  //including side-effect stuff like this
  //self.store.createRecord('foo', someHash);
  return fooz; //new code
});
```

The above doesn't work the first time around as foo.get('bar') is a promise. But this is only a problem the first time through (subsequent $.ajax requests seems to have all the bar objects cached so it's a non issue)

What's strange is that before I even boot the app I've already pulled down all the bar data in the init (shown below). So why does ember-data even need to resolve the promise for "bar" when technically that data should already be in the store locally?

```
App.initializer({
  name: 'bootstrap',
  initialize: function() {
    App.deferReadiness();
    var store = App.__container__.lookup("store:main");
    var bars = store.find('bar');
    var configurations = store.find('configuration');
    Ember.RSVP.all([bars, configurations]).then(results) {
      App.advanceReadiness();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's separate a few things here

### Store cache

```
this.store.all('foo').clear();
```

just breaks the internal `all` filter until a `foo` record is modified/added/removed forcing the filter to recalculate for the record in the store.  I say this to show that clear isn't removing the records from ED's store.

**Example (click the button, watch the console, read the fun action code)**

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/103/edit

That being said it isn't the ajax that's being cached, it's the property/relationship on the record instance that's being cached (and the record).

The proper way to remove the records of a type from the store is `store.unloadAll('foo')`

### Promiselandia

I know you're already familiar with promises, so this part may be worthless, but, worth documenting

The async relationships are really cool because they return `PromiseObject`/`PromiseArray` for `belongsTo`/`hasMany`.  The `PromiseObject`/`PromiseArray` extend `ObjectProxy`/`ArrayProxy` (these are the same things that `ObjectController`/`ArrayController` extend).  This essentially gives the `PromiseObject`/`PromiseArray` the ability to proxy getting/setting of properties to the model underneath.  In this case the setting/getting happens on the promise doesn't "work" until the promise has been resolved (it won't crash, just return undefined).  *Caveat, methods don't exist on the promise, so you can't call save on the promise and expect it to work.

#### Ex. using your models.

```
var foo = this.store.find('foo', 1);

var bar = foo.get('bar');  // PromiseObject

bar.get('name'); // undefined
```

**later, bar has resolved, bar is still the PromiseObject**

```
bar.get('name'); // billy
```

**foo will keep returning the PromiseObject**

```
var bar2 = foo.get('bar');  // PromiseObject

bar2.get('name'); // billy
```

**saving**

```
bar.save(); // Boom no workey

bar.then(function(realBar){
  realBar.save(); // workey
});
```

In your case I have 3 recommendations

### Build your own promise, resolve when you want, use Ember.RSVP.all on the records needed (respecting that they may or may not be resolved yet, hence async)

```
var self = this;

var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  self.store.find('foo').then(function(foos) {
    Em.RSVP.all(foos.getEach('bar')).then(function(bars){

      var filtered = bars.filterBy('name', 'bazz');

      resolve(filtered);
    });
  });
});
return promise;
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/104/edit

### async properties

A lot of times with async objects/properties that aren't resolved during the model hook (which blocks on promises and wait's until they are resolved) a good trick is to set a placeholder object etc.

```
var items = [];

controller.set('model', items);

// promise from above
promise.then(function(records){
  items.pushObjects(records.toArray()); // toArray may or may not apply
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/106/edit