# Ember.js load associated has many records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

Surely there is a better way to access associated records in Ember.js than this – here the only option I successfully implemented was to load the record, then manually do a Ransack query to my Rails API for "entries" that match my invoice id.

invoice.coffee:

```
`import Ember from "ember"`

InvoicesInvoiceRoute = Ember.Route.extend

    model: (invoice)->
        @store.find "invoice", invoice.invoice_id

    setupController: (controller,model) ->
        controller.set 'model', model
        controller.set 'entries', @store.find 'time_entry', q:
            invoice_id_eq: model.get 'id'

`export default InvoicesInvoiceRoute`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Ember-data, you could simply [sideload](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships) the records or make the relation `async` to make Ember fetch them whenever they are called, like so:

```
// Invoice Model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  entries: DS.hasMany('entry', { async: true })
});
```

*Sorry for not drinking coffee mate ; )*

Comment: Thanks so much for response Timo: Curiously I do have async true already set up. So maybe I'm just trying to access them in the wrong way – model.get('time_entries') should work, yeah?

Comment: It would be `model.get('entries')`. Does the invoice payload hold an array with entries like so: `"entries":[1,2,3]`? Is an XHR call for entries being made at all?

Comment: `entries` is a promise until it resolves, this post explains: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20938578/1790950

Comment: Timo –– thanks a million. My fault was inded not providing an array of time_entry_ids within my invoice records in Rails API. Once I'd added that to the Rails serializer, everything worked as expected.